# Can I turn a Piezo Buzzer into an ultrasonic Mist Maker?

Tags: piezo-buzzer, piezoelectricity

You may have been reading my questions for a project I am doing.  This one is a bit off the wall - I purchased a small 'bottle-top-humidifier' off of amazon and opened it up just to take out the ultrasonic mist maker.

I've been scouring the web for a couple of hours to try to find JUST the piezo ceramic disc that generates the mist.  I've come across a few articles explaining piezoelectronics and it seems that a piezo buzzer and a piezo mist maker are made up of the same materials.

Is this correct?  Can I go purchase some piezo buzzers and use them to create fog? Does anyone have any literature on this?

Comment: You should make separate questions for different questions.

Comment: @Samuel edited.

Comment: Mist-generators use a fairly thick piezo slab which resonates at around a megahertz.   A piezo beeper, if it could be driven with hundreds of volts, might create some water droplets or spray, but not mist or fog.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Piezo transducers for creating audible sound operate in a **bending mode** and resonate, typically, at 2kHz to 4kHz.

Piezo tranducers used in nebulizers operate in a **thickness mode** and resonate, typically, at 1MHz to 2.5MHz (1.6MHz is a popular choice).

They're quite different (1000:1 in resonant frequency)- just go and buy the right thing for the job.

Comment: Spehro, Quick question - would I be able to use a TL1610 to create a 1.7MHz frequency to power the piezo transducer?  http://www.linear.com/product/LT1610

Comment: Typically you want to operate right at the resonance point, so some kind of self-resonating circuit is indicated, for example:http://tinyurl.com/l877qsh

Comment: Ah yes, I saw this circuit.  I suppose I'm too new to this, but is this possible with a small amount of DC voltage? instead of the 48V of AC?

Comment: Yes, DC is fine, but relatively high voltage is usually required to get enough power.

Answer (score 0):

Newer mist makers operate at only 113khz, and normal piezo discs do work. Great Scott has a video about it on You tube.